# All forms of integers

Tags: complex-numbers

I had a question, just a beginner so are all integers represented by the forms $$4n \\ 4n+1 \\ 4n+2 \\ 4n+3$$

Thanks and regards
Sorry for this question, if it seems too easy...

Comment: Do you think it's true? Why do you think it's true? And what would it take to convince you that it is true, or how would you try to convince someone else that it is true?

Comment: @PNDas Yes, think about the words "even" and "odd".

Comment: This is an 2. 000 years old theorem by Euclid.

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:complex-numbers] rather than [tag:integers]?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When you divide any integer by $4$, your remainder will be one of $0,1,2,3$.

Potentially you may be curious about dividing *negative* numbers by $4$ (e.g. what is $-23\div 4$ ?), but even there you can take the remainder to be positive. You just need to round your initial number *down* to the first smaller number divisible by $4$. For example, when dividing $-23$ by $4$, notice $-24$ is divisible by $4$ and so the quotient can be taken to be $-6$ and remainder to be $1$ (rather than quotient $-5$ and remainder $-3$).